# how to combine two if's?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code where the second if loop should execute only after the first condition is satisfied,is there a way to combine these to if loops?

```
    if Pline=mPL:
    if bestTime == None or bestTime < lastTime:
        bestTime = lastTime
        Time=(bestTime.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
        bestLocation = lastLocation
```

Comment: Use and, or for combining two conditions..

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: `if Pline=mPL:` isn't valid Python syntax, so this can't be working code.  I wouldn't have bothered to mention it except both the current answers have the same error.. BTW, `bestTime is None` is considered more idiomatic than `bestTime == None`.

Comment: `if pLine == mpL and (bestTime == None or bestTime < lastTime):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `and` condition:

```
if (Pline=mPL) and ((bestTime == None) or (bestTime < lastTime)):
        bestTime = lastTime
        Time=(bestTime.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
        bestLocation = lastLocation
```